# How to convert IEEE754 float to fixed-point in deterministic way?

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754, fixed-point, deterministic

I need to convert a 32 bit IEEE754 float to a signed Q19.12 fixed-point format. The problem is that it must be done in a fully deterministic way, so the usual (int)(f * (1 << FRACTION_SHIFT)) is not suitable, since it uses non-deterministic floating point math. Are there any "bit fiddling" or similar deterministic conversion methods?

Edit: Deterministic in this case is assumed as: given the same floating point data achieve exactly same conversion results on different platforms.

Comment: Neither is floating point: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: The interesting question is how you obtained that float deterministically in the first way.

Comment: The float is a non mutable data serialized from disk, that comes from a single source. Ie, there are no operations performed with that float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @StephenCanon's answer might be right about this particular case being fully deterministic, I've decided to stay on the safer side, and still do the conversion manually. This is the code I have ended up with (thanks to @CodesInChaos for pointers on how to do this):

```
public static Fixed FromFloatSafe(float f) {
    // Extract float bits
    uint fb = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
    uint sign = (uint)((int)fb >> 31);
    uint exponent = (fb >> 23) & 0xFF;
    uint mantissa = (fb & 0x007FFFFF);

    // Check for Infinity, SNaN, QNaN
    if (exponent == 255) {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    // Add mantissa's assumed leading 1
    } else if (exponent != 0) {
        mantissa |= 0x800000;
    }

    // Mantissa with adjusted sign
    int raw = (int)((mantissa ^ sign) - sign);
    // Required float's radix point shift to convert to fixed point
    int shift = (int)exponent - 127 - FRACTION_SHIFT + 1;

    // Do the shifting and check for overflows
    if (shift > 30) {
        throw new OverflowException();
    } else if (shift > 0) {
        long ul = (long)raw << shift;
        if (ul > int.MaxValue) {
            throw new OverflowException();
        }
        if (ul < int.MinValue) {
            throw new OverflowException();
        }
        raw = (int)ul;
    } else {
        raw = raw >> -shift;
    }

    return Fixed.FromRaw(raw);
}
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work on both little-endian & big-endian platforms. `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` can be used to detect byte order.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point is not non-deterministic.  Where did you get that preposterous hypothesis?

Expanding a little bit:
`1 << FRACTION_SHIFT` is an exact power of two, and therefore represented exactly in floating point.  Multiplication by an exact power of two is exact (unless overflow/underflow occurs, but in that case there isn't a meaningful fixed-point representation anyway, so you don't care).  So the only possible source of rounding is the conversion to integer, which is fully specified by C#; so not only is the result deterministic, but you will get portable identical results.

Comment: Most math on `float` and `double` is not deterministic on the CLR. This specific case might be, but in general it isn't.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: it certainly is deterministic.  It may not be *portable*, but the same code run with the same options on the same hardware gives the same result every time.

Comment: Even that is an optimistic assumption, and not guaranteed, even if it is mostly true in practice. The JITter has a lot of freedom, and it's not guaranteed to return the same code every time.

Comment: The JITter may have a lot of freedom, but it is also deterministic.  In any event, it doesn't actually matter, because the result is fully specified in this case (assuming the input is in the representable range of the output type).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Stephen Canon explained that representing `1 << FRACTION_SHIFT` in floating-point is exact, that multiplication by it is exact, and that the C# specification fully specifies (i.e., determines) the result of converting to integer. Therefore, a conforming implementation must return a deterministic result. What is the basis for your claim that an implementation may return different results? Does the language standard permit this? Can you show an example?

Comment: This specific case may be deterministic, but the first sentence of the answer talks about floating point math in general, where this is clearly not true.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Floating-point math is deterministic.  Period.  Do you imagine that there is an entropy source in the ALU, supplying the low bits of floating-point results?  "Deterministic" has a very specific meaning; "non-deterministic" behavior requires more than dependence on complex state that might be difficult to observe or predict.

Comment: In general the JITter is free to create code that behaves slightly different on each run, so that the result of a computation changes from run to run of the program. A Java style recompiling JITter could even change the behavior within a single run of the program. This specific case is probably not affected, but general multiplications are.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: do you believe that the JITter makes those decisions non-deterministically?

Comment: The current implementation is relatively consistent. But it's free to do so in principle. For example it might change the implementation depending on performance measurements, which certainly are not deterministic.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The question is tagged C#. C# completely specifies the results of rounding. Although the language implementation is free to produce different code to produce those results, it is not permitted to produce different results. If program execution produces a result of rounding that is different from what the language standard specifies, the implementation has violated the standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C# allows computation using higher precision, which for many calculations changes the result. In this specific case the code is precision independent, so it should be well defined.

Comment: @StephenCanon: while you're right that floating point math is deterministic on the same ALU given exact same starting configuration and data, but it's not deterministic across the different platforms. I have updated the question to include that I'm specifically interested in determinism across the platforms.

Comment: Down-voting based on updated question. This answer no longer applies when lock-step determinism across different platforms is required (for example, to synchronize a multiplayer game simulation).

Comment: Explanation I got about this is: For multiplication/division, if one of the FP numbers is power of two number (2^x), significant/mantissa won't change during calculation. Only exponent will change (point will move). So rounding will never happen.  
**Example**: A number like 2^32 is represented as (exponent: 32, mantissa: 1). If we multiply this with another float (exp, man), the result is (exp + 32, man * 1). For division, the result is (expo - 32, man * 1). Multiplying the mantissa by 1 doesn't change the mantissa, so it doesn't matter how many bits it has.

Answer (score 1):

If determinism is absolutely required, I'd parse the content as an integer, and do the conversion manually.

First extract the exponent. If it's too small return `0`, if it's too large, throw an overflow exception.

Next extract sign and mantissa (remember the implicit leading `1`). If the sign bit is `1`, flip the sign of the mantissa. Finally execute a bit shift by the exponent combined with a bias.

I also wrote a [soft float implementation](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/SoftFloat/blob/master/SoftFloatTest/SoftFloat.cs), that guarantees determinism. It's pretty incomplete, but the parts you need are implemented.